# Tapestry onEvent issue

Tags: tapestry

I'm having an issue with updating chained select components - what I have keyed seems to be working but its giving me a big ugly error message.

Component.tml (relevant section)

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3>Powers:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
        <t:select t:id="powersSelect" t:model="powersModel"
            t:value="powersItem" t:encoder="itemEncoder"
             t:validate="required" t:blankOption="ALWAYS" t:blankLabel="Choose..." zone="groundsZone" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3>Grounds:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
        <t:zone t:id="groundsZone" id="groundsZone" visible="false">
            <t:select  t:model="groundsModel"
                t:value="groundsItem" t:encoder="itemEncoder"
                t:validate="required" t:blankOption="ALWAYS" t:blankLabel="Choose..."/>
        </t:zone>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Component.java (relevant section)

```
     @InjectComponent
    private Zone groundsZone;

    @Inject
    private SelectModelFactory selectModelFactory;

    @Property
    private SelectModel powersModel, groundsModel;

    @Property
    StandingDataItem powersStandingDataItem, groundsStandingDataItem;

@SetupRender
void setupRender() {
    powersList = service.getList()
    powersModel = selectModelFactory.create(powersList, "displayText");

   //included as I was getting a null pointer without instantiating 
    groundsList = new ArrayList<StandingDataItem>();
    groundsModel = selectModelFactory.create(new ArrayList<StandingDataItem>(), "displayText");
}

@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "powersSelect")
    Object updateGrounds(StandingDataItem sdi) {
        powersStandingDataItem=sdi;
        groundsList = service.getList()
        groundsModel = selectModelFactory.create(groundsList, "displayText");
        return groundsZone.getBody();
    }
```

However I keep hitting the following error and have been unable to resolve. The service method call completes, returns the expected list and both the Select components contain the information expected - however I get a big red ugly error message takign up half the screen saying...

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getFormEventManager' of null 
at klass.Tapestry.FieldEventManager.Class.create.initialize (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/tapestry.js:1588:38) 
at new klass (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/scriptaculous_1_9_0/prototype.js:101:23) 
at Element.addMethods.getFieldEventManager (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/tapestry.js:841:23) 
at HTMLSelectElement._methodized [as getFieldEventManager] (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/scriptaculous_1_9_0/prototype.js:438:23) 
at http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/tapestry.js:1145:26 
at http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/scriptaculous_1_9_0/prototype.js:825:18 
at klass._each (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/scriptaculous_1_9_0/prototype.js:1237:7) 
at klass.each (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/scriptaculous_1_9_0/prototype.js:824:12) 
at T5.extendInitializers.validate (http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/tapestry.js:1135:14) 
at http://localhost:8080/nottsStops/assets/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tapestry/tapestry.js:268:23
Ajax failure: Status 200 for /nottsStops/stopsentrybuild.powerscomponent.powersselect:change: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getFormEventManager' of null
Communication with the server failed: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getFormEventManager' of null
```

I'm using tapestry 5.3.7. The component is part of a form made up of many sub components - none of the other sub components have this issue (likely because this is the only one using a chained select). Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong/ why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear I found the answer (although I have to admit I don't understand the behavior). I had included a custom component in my tml file just before the select. The custom component contained a  element and this appeared to have caused the form to close before the  tag (more likely messed with the tml structure than close the form early as there were no other errors). Removing the  from my custom component has resolved the issue.